# VS 2015 unit tests fail after upgrading from VS2013

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

After upgrading a VS2013 solution to VS2015 couple of unit tests fail. They're pass on VS2013. Is this due to some new process that Microsoft introduced? I haven't seen anything on line to this effect. I'm pasting the code below.

```
    public void GetIntegerFromCodeTableColumnNotFoundTest()
    {
        DataSet mockedDS = new DataSet();
        DataTable mockedDT = new DataTable("TestTable");
        mockedDT.Columns.Add("FieldName");
        mockedDT.Columns.Add("Length");

        mockedDS.Tables.Add(mockedDT);

        DataRow mockedDR = mockedDT.NewRow();
        mockedDR["FieldName"] = "FirstName";
        mockedDR["Length"] = "11";
        mockedDT.Rows.Add(mockedDR);
        TableManager mgr = new TestTableManager();
        IDataCache mockDataCache = MockRepository.GenerateMock<IDataCache>();
        DataCache.Instance = mockDataCache;
        mockDataCache.Expect(a => a.GetCache("Testkey")).Return(mockedDS);

        try
        {
            float retVal = (float)mgr.GetIntegerValueFromCodeTable("TestTable", "Junk", "FirstName", "Length", true);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(ex.Message, "Cannot find column [Junk].");
        }
    }
```

The exception message returned, matches the test message but the error returned is this: Test method GetIntegerFromCodeTableColumnNotFoundTest did not throw expected exception System.Data.EvaluateException.

I've looked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42206980/unit-tests-in-vs-2015-versus-vs2013) but mine fail regardless how they're run, be it in debug, or one at the time, or all.

Comment: Are you using the `[TestMethod]` attribute for your unit tests?

Comment: Yes. [TestMethod, ExpectedException(typeof(System.Data.EvaluateException))]